# Is a recreational drone operator considered remote pilot in command?

Tags: regulations, faa

A drone pilot flying under part 107 is referred to as "remote pilot in command." Does this term also apply to someone operating a drone under the exemption for recreational flyers?

Comment: Recreational flyers are not flying under part 107.